# C# - How to continue after failing to attach debugger - System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()

Tags: c#, debugging

I attach a debugger by passing '-d' as a command line parameter to my console app. That causes the following code to be called;

```
bool attachedDebugger = false;
try
{
   attachedDebugger = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
}
catch (Exception) { }
finally
{
   Console.WriteLine(attachedDebugger ? "Debugger Attached" : "Failed to attach debugger");
}
```

After the Visual Studio 2010 JIT window pops up I sometimes change my mind and don't want to debug, so I dismiss the dialog. If I don't attach one then the Application exits immediately without anything being written to the console.

I know that this it a bit of an edge use case, I should just remove the '-d' from the command line if I don't want to debug. The reason for my question is that I wish to understand what's happening.

I thought the finally block is *always* called, furthermore I would expect my application to continue if we fail to attach a debugger.

- Why is nothing printed to the console
  if I decline attaching a debugger?
- Does `Debugger.Launch()` call
  `System.Exit` on failure to attach?

**EDIT** Thanks @Moo-Juice I now know that a return value of `false` implies a debugger was already attached but the questions above remain unresolved.

Comment: The boolean value returned is `false` if a debugger is *already attached*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [reported bug in dotnet 4.0](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/611486/debugger-launch-is-now-crashing-my-net-application-after-upgrading-to-net-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* that the `finally{}` block isn't being executed?

Could the console just be shutting down so-quickly-it-looks-like-instantly?

Comment: Running with ctrl+F5 should prevent that